# what are uri, contentValues

Tags: android, uri, android-contentresolver

Can anyone explain me about each term that I have used in working with calendar events?

1. `Uri event_uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/" + "events");`
   What is uri here, what actually is content, as we can initialize int value to 0? Is it
   possible to initialize a uri with a default value?
2. `Uri reminder_uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/" + "reminders");`
   What signifies these uri? What are the differences between `event_uri` and `reminder_uri`?
3. `ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

   values.put("calendar_id", 1);

   values.put("title", str);

   values.put("description", m_strDescription);`
   What does the first one do? `values.put("calendar_id", 1);`
4. `ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();`
   What is the use of the content resolver? Sometimes we write:

   `Uri u = cr.insert(event_uri, values)`
   What is this uri? How does it differ from the first two uris e.g `event_uri` and `reminder_uri`

   Again `values.put("event_id", Long.parseLong(event.getLastPathSegment())); 
   cr.insert(remindar_uri, values);`

   What does it do?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Regarding questions 1 and 2, A `Uri` is an address that points to something of significance. In the case of `ContentProvider`s, the `Uri` is usually used to determine which table to use. So `event_uri` points to the events table and the `reminder_uri` points to the reminders table. There is really no "default value" for uris.

Regarding question 3, the `ContentValues` is essentially a set of key-value pairs, where the key represents the column for the table and the value is the value to be inserted in that column. So in the case of `values.put("calendar_id", 1);`, the column is "calendar_id" and the value being inserted for that column is 1.

Regarding question 4, the `ContentResolver` is what android uses to resolve `Uri`s to `ContentProvider`s. Anyone can create a `ContentProvider` and Android has `ContentProvider`s for the Calendar, Contacts, etc.. The `insert()` method on a `ContentResolver` returns the `Uri` of the inserted row. So in questions 1 and 2, those `Uri`s pointed to the table but `Uri`s are hierarchical so they can resolve to a specific row. For example:

`content://com.android.calendar/events` points to the events table, but

`content://com.android.calendar/events/1` points to the row in the events table with id 1.

Keep in mind, that this is the usual behavior, but the providing `ContentProvider` can customize the uris to be resolved differently.

I would strongly recommend reading the [ContentProvider docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html), especially the section on [Content URIs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#ContentURIs).

---

From the previously recommended documentation:

> In the previous lines of code, the full URI for the "words" table is:
>
> `content://user_dictionary/words`
>
> where the `user_dictionary` string is
>   the provider's authority, and `words` string is the table's path. The
>   string `content://` (the **scheme**) is always present, and identifies this
>   as a content URI.

Answer (score 0):

ContentValues:

```
public final class
ContentValues
extends Object
implements Parcelable have public methods
like: String getAsString(String KEY) , void put(Sring KEY, String value)
e.g.

public void createEntry(String name, String number){
    ContentValues cval = new ContentValues();
    cval.put(KEY_NAME, name);   // KEY_NAME is key just like parameter in put(String key)
    ....
    ....
    ....


}
```