# Sharing photos from app to google+

Tags: android, google-plus

I am trying to share images from my app to social networks. I have implemented `Facebook` and `Twitter`, but at `Google+`, I can't see any way.

I have seen apps like `Instagram` etc. share images on Google+. However, on Google+ developers the only thing that I can find is this:

> The latest version of the Google+ Android SDK, including the SDK Tools
>   component (not yet available).

Can anyone please show me how I can share my images on Google+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share media (photos and albums) on Google+ with the `ACTION_SEND` intent.
The media can be specified within the [EXTRA_STREAM](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM), and needs to contain the [content URI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7492847/313790) of the media.

Here's an example:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        MY_PICTURE_FILE_NAME);
String photoUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
        getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), null, null);

Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(MyActivity.this)
        .setText("Sharing an image on Google!")
        .setType("image/jpeg")
        .setStream(Uri.parse(photoUri))
        .getIntent();
startActivity(shareIntent);
file.delete();
```