# Why doesn't Uri.getPath() return the actual path?

Tags: android, android-intent

There are multiple questions about this issue (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789276/android-get-real-path-by-uri-getpath), for example) and the solution seems to be to create a `getRealPathFromURI` method which uses a pretty hacky method to figure out the path of the file. My question is why is this necessary in the first place? Why doesn't `getPath` return the actual path of the file?

My use case is that I'm receiving an ACTION_SEND intent with MIME type `*/*` and want to copy the file to another location, so I need the full path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not understand what a `Uri` is. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426451/what-are-uri-contentvalues) to know what it is all about (they don't necessarily point to files on the device all the time), also you have to understand what `ContentProvider`s are. And then use the solution in the question you've linked already to get the actual image file path from the device.